# Create an empty symbolic matrix and predefine the dimension in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, symbolic-math

I want want to do some string calculation using Matlab, and then stored the value in an matrix.

For numerical study, I often predefined the dimensions in Matlab using `zeros` to create a 4*4 array.

```
a = zeros(4)
```

Now I want to do the same thing for the symbolic matrix. Obviously `zeros` didn't work at this time.

I tried to copy the official tutorial at this page http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html

```
a = sym('0' ,4)  % error
```

Still didn't work.

Now I have do use the ugly code like this

```
a = sym('[0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0]');
```

Since I will use iterations, and dimension of the matrix grows every time. This method is not convenient.

Do you have any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

> Num = sym(Num) converts a number or a numeric matrix Num to symbolic form.

```
a=sym(zeros(4,4))
```

Comment: You could also do `a = sym(zeros(4))` with the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Can't try but suspect that the variables get initialized as zero by default. 
For example when using

```
a = sym('a' ,[2 2])
```

Comment: Creates a Matrix, but does not initialise with zero.

Comment: @Daniel Then I will delete this soon, but could you tell me what it initializes with if its not zero?

Comment: 4 unknown complex numbers, similar to the math expression a in C^4